# Coefficients estimation via covarinace matrices in linear regression

Tags: regression, estimation, linear, covariance-matrix, high-dimensional

In linear regression I know the OLS-estimator $\beta = (X'X)^{-1}X'y $, but if the number of possible regressors $p$ is high, e.g. higher than the number of observations $N$, this is not a feasible option. I recently saw this alternative formula for estimation via the covarinace matrices: $\beta = Var(X)^{-1}Cov(X, y)$. Can someone explain to me how to obtain this (in the best case from scratch) or recommend any literature?